# Rundeck failed ldaps 636 authetication with MS LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, jaas, rundeck

Unable to authenticate with laps (636) with MS Ldap.

Rundeck installed in Ubuntu 20.04. Version APIVERSION : 41, BUILD : 4.7.0-20221006

Thank you for the help.

-Follow https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap
-Open a question on google groups named "Rundeck how to do a Microsoft LDAP authetication test"
-Restarted rundeckd service after every jaas file change.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/PLAihTfHfrY/m/w4g5hBc8DAAJ

Comment: When you say "MS LDAP" do you refer to Active Directory? I have not tested using "MS LDAP". But you can add the service certificate to the java cacert and should work https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/tnpm/1.4.2?topic=security-import-certificate-jre-keystore (the same java that you use for launch Rundeck ) Regards.

Comment: Configuration in "/etc/default/rundeckd" also points to certs location:

RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Drundeck.jaaslogin=true \
       -Dloginmodule.conf.name=/etc/rundeck/jaas-loginmodule.conf \
       -Dloginmodule.name=multiauth \
       -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore"

Comment: Windows LDAP. Certificates added with " keytool -import -alias CompanyAD -file AD.cert -keystore  /etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore -storepass adminadmin" and "keytool -import -alias CompanyAD -file AD.cert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit"
Comunication works with same jaas file using 389, and my AD name. 636 port is open between both servers. 
Certificate was downloaded with " openssl s_client -showcerts -connect MY-AD-NAME:636"

Comment: Try without the " -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore" parameter in the rundeckd file, that's not needed if you already added the cert to the java cacert. With that parameter, rundeck try out to find the cert in the truststore file, not in the java cacert.

Comment: Edited jaas file and removed " -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore". And now it´s working. Thank you.

Comment: "    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    providerUrl="ldaps://MY AD:636"
    bindDn="name@domain"
    bindPassword="pass..."
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="true"
    ...
    userRdnAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    userIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
    userObjectClass="user"
    ....

Comment: Also before added AD name to /etc/hosts ir order to resolve AD with same cn that the certificated. Also added CA cert to ubuntu trusted certs.

Comment: Let me add the answer then. Great news!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore` parameter in the `rundeckd` file, that's not needed if you already added the cert to the java cacert file.

With that parameter, rundeck tries to find the cert in the truststore file, not in the java cacert.